# HTTPError: Internal Server Error while scraping a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pandas-datareader

I have tried to fix my code in a lot of ways, but I keep getting a `HTTPError: Internal Server Error`.

Someone told me to use `pd.read_html` instead of `pd.read_excel` since the excel one gave me an error about excel file type, but I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Either way I'm getting an error.

```
import urllib3
import requests
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

dataframe=[]
url = "https://vialidad.mop.gob.cl/Paginas/PasadasVehiculares.aspx"
url1="https://vialidad.mop.gob.cl"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
rawpage = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rawpage.content, 'html5lib')

for link in soup.select('a[href*=".xls"]'):
   
    s=url1+link["href"]
    print(s)
    c = pd.read_excel(s)
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure why `pd.read_excel` is raising a HTTPError, but as a workaround, you can first fetch the Excel file with `requests.get` and then load it through `read_excel` by creating an in-memory file object using `BytesIO`.

```python
from io import BytesIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
import xlrd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

dataframe = []
url = "https://vialidad.mop.gob.cl/Paginas/PasadasVehiculares.aspx"
url1 = "https://vialidad.mop.gob.cl"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
rawpage = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rawpage.content, 'html5lib')

for link in soup.select('a[href*=".xls"]'):

    s = url1 + link["href"]
    print(s)
    try:
        r = requests.get(s)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as e: # Some of the .xls links throw 401 errors
        print(e.response.status_code, "error for", s)
        continue
    c = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(r.content))
    print(c)
```

Comment: Sorry stormer, took a while on give you the solution, forgot to do it, but YES!, it solve the problem, use the cache.